# Is the empty set a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

I think the empty set satisfies all of the axioms of a vector space except the one about the existence of an additive identity. Is this right?

Comment: [Wikipedia's definition and axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) suggest you need to specify a field so that you have a scalar multiplicative identity.

Comment: If the question is whether $(E,+,\cdot)$ can be a vector space if $E=\varnothing$, then I think the question answers itself: the additive identity is missing, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No! If $(E,+,\cdot)$ is a vector space then $(E,+)$ is an abelian group so it contains a neutral element which is the zero vector hence $E\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: That's exactly what I said, that the empty set has no zero vector!

Comment: It's obvious that the empty set doesn't contain a zero vector since it doesn't contain any element but my answer explains why the empty set isn't a vector space.

Comment: That's also what I said in the question, that since the empty set doesn't contain a 0 vector then it isn't  a vector space; Thanks anyway, I like your answer since it's technical.

Comment: @user209799 Perhaps people are confused because you did not actually write "and therefore it is not a vector space" at the end of your first sentence, although evidently that's what you were thinking. Sometimes it's worth stating the obvious.

Answer (score 16):

The empty set is empty (no elements), hence it fails to have the zero vector as an element.

Since it fails to contain zero vector, it *cannot* be a vector space.